# Create hundreds of TimeSeries & Train-/Testsets with loop or function

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

## MWE

I have a dataset with a bit more than 1 Mio rows, containing several 100 TimeSeries. Here a simplified MWE of this data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"dtime":["2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-03", "2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-03",
                           "2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-03","2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-03"],
                   "Type":["A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","D","D","D"],
                   "Value":[1,2,3,4,6,8,1,5,8,3,1,2]})

+----+------------+--------+---------+
|    | dtime      | Type   |   Value |
|----+------------+--------+---------|
|  0 | 2022-01-01 | A      |       1 |
|  1 | 2022-01-02 | A      |       2 |
|  2 | 2022-01-03 | A      |       3 |
|  3 | 2022-01-01 | B      |       4 |
|  4 | 2022-01-02 | B      |       6 |
|  5 | 2022-01-03 | B      |       8 |
|  6 | 2022-01-01 | C      |       1 |
|  7 | 2022-01-02 | C      |       5 |
|  8 | 2022-01-03 | C      |       8 |
|  9 | 2022-01-01 | D      |       3 |
| 10 | 2022-01-02 | D      |       1 |
| 11 | 2022-01-03 | D      |       2 |
+----+------------+--------+---------+
```

`Type` represents the TimeSeries-Group, so A is one TimeSerie, B another and so on.

---

## Goal

I want to train a multi dimensional TimeSeries-NN (like provided by the `unit8-darts`package).

```
from darts.models import NBEATSModel
model = NBEATSModel(input_chunk_length=50, output_chunk_length=50, n_epochs=25)
model.fit([train1, train2, train3, train4])
```

For this I need the `Type` separated and converted into TimeSeries format and finally split into train/test.
Like this:

```
from darts import TimeSeries

split_date = "2022-01-02"

series1 = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(df[df["Type"] == "A"], "dtime", "Value", freq="D", fillna_value=0)
series2 = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(df[df["Type"] == "B"], "dtime", "Value", freq="D", fillna_value=0)
series3 = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(df[df["Type"] == "C"], "dtime", "Value", freq="D", fillna_value=0)
series4 = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(df[df["Type"] == "D"], "dtime", "Value", freq="D", fillna_value=0)
train1, val1 = series1.split_before(pd.Timestamp(split_date))
train2, val2 = series2.split_before(pd.Timestamp(split_date))
train3, val3 = series3.split_before(pd.Timestamp(split_date))
train4, val4 = series4.split_before(pd.Timestamp(split_date))
```

But as the real world data has way more than 4 `Type` to do this procedure manually would be an overkill and so I'm looking for a solution with a loop or a function to create this `train`, `test` and `series` TS-objects.

And **additionally** to this the sequential `series`, `train` and `test` TS-objects I want to create a list containing each `trainX` name like:

```
ts_list = [train1, train2, train3, train4]
```

---

Does somebody has an idea how I can do this? I'm happy for any proposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried to use a groupby over Type column in a loop :

```
train_list = []
for ts_type, group in df.groupby('Type'):
    series = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(group, "dtime", "Value", freq="D", fillna_value=0)
    train, val = series.split_before(pd.Timestamp(split_date))
    train_list.append(train)
```

But, with a lot of data it could becomes computively expensive to use loop with Pandas. So maybe a better solution can be found (using other tools like spark for exemple).

Comment: Thank you very much for time and solution. I upvoted it. But I still have the problem, that with this I don't have the `series1`, `series2`, `train1`, `train2` and so on, which I need for prediction.

Comment: Cool if it help ! I'm not sure to understand your needs here. You can create another empty list `series_list = []` and fill it in the loop as for train. But I didn't get the problem to access `train1`, `train2` as you can get them from list using indices `train1 = train_list[0]`.

Comment: You're right. I will check it, thank you! For now I accept your answer (maybe another one has a faster solution, than I will check this, but I don't think so :-). Merci beaucoup!

Answer (score 0):

The answer given above looks good. I would add that before implementing this, you should probably ask yourself whether:

- You want to model your data using one time series per group. In this case, the proposed option looping over groups looks good. You should probably use this representation if the groups representing distinct "observations" of some the same underlying phenomenon (e.g., heart rate series of two distinct patients).
- You want to model your data using one time series for all groups, where each group make one dimension of this (multivariate) time series. You should use this when each of the group represent a distinct dimension making up an observation (e.g., heart rate and blood pressure of a single patient). In this latter case, you should transform the dataframe to have the groups in separate columns, and call `TimeSeries.from_dataframe()` only once.

Comment: I think this is better off as a comment than a distinct answer: the ordering of answers in SO can/may change, so "the answer given above" isn't a great reference point.

Comment: Thank you very much. But it's not a multivariate TimeSeries, it's a multi dimensional. According to your example. It's not about blood pressure and heart rate, it's about blood pressure of person A, Person B, person C. They don't have a direct effect on each other, but they might have the same behavior. So if you learn from one what happens if this value increases, this might have the same impact on others (very simplified said).

Comment: OK I see. Then yes you should build multiple TimeSeries objects (option 1). This way you'll be building a collection of univariate series. I don't think you should think of the series as multi-dimensional. Rather, you have a collection of 1-dimensional series which together make your problem's data points.